# UITableViewCell: How to prevent blue selection background w/o borking isSelected property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. I have set the `contentView` of my cell subclass to 
a custom `UIView` class in which i am overriding `-drawRect:` and doing all of the drawing there.

Also, I am setting `cell.contentView.opaque = NO` in order to achieve transparency in certain areas of the cell (unfortunately, a backgroud image behind the table must show thru each cell in certain parts to achieve a stylistic effect. i know this is a performance hit. it must be so).

Problem: I still see the default pretty blue gradient background being drawn behind my cell (in the transparent areas) when it is selected or highlighted (being pressed). This is obscuring the image behind the table, which is bad.

Goal: To prevent the blue gradient background from appearing, but still be able to inspect the `cell.isSelected` and `cell.isHighlighted` properties from within `-[MyContentView drawRect:]` to determine how to draw my own custom selection/highlighting.

What I've tried:

1. setting `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` has the desired effect of preventing the pretty blue gradient selection background, but also prevents the `cell.isSelected` and `cell.isHighlighted` properties from being properly set, which means i cannot do my own custom selection/highlight drawing
2. setting `cell.selectionBackgroundView = nil` and `cell.backgroundView = nil` in the cell's `-init` or `-prepareForReuse` method does not prevent  the blue gradient selection background
3. setting `cell.selectionBackgroundView = nil` in the `-[MyContentView -drawRect:]` method *does* have the desired effect of preventing the blue gradient selection background, but that seems very janky
4. overriding -[UITableViewCell setSelected:animated:] to be a no-op. this does not have the desired effect of preventing the blue gradient selection background

Answer (score 47, accepted):

An excellent resource on customizing UITableViews has been [this post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) by Matt Gallagher. What you'll want to do is set the selectedBackgroundView to a new view (instead of nil) that is either transparent or a UIImageView.

Comment: Jason, thank you! your suggestion has done the trick. a couple of notes:

- I'm not sure how you gleaned that info from the article as it was not one of the significant points made. but good job :)

- that article is def very informative. unfortunately, it also seems a litle misleading in that it ignores the common case where u need more cell customization in which case it is better to subclass and override the contentView's -drawRect: to achieve fast scrolling as explained here:

http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/

Comment: Just to further clarify this for future readers, instead of setting any cell.selectionStyle, set cell.selectedBackgroundView to a UIView - I set it to a UIView with the same bounds as my cell, and then set alpha to 0.5 to highlight the cell but still leave everything visible.  Don't forget to call [self setNeedsDisplay] in your setSelected method!

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner Everything with this method works, except despite setting `alpha` to 0.5 and calling `setNeedsDisplay`, the selected background colour is completely white and covers the cell's view when selected (despite having set the `UIView`/`selectedBackgroundView`'s background colour to `clearColor`). Any ideas?

Answer (score 67):

You must also override setHighlighted: to prevent the blue gradient from ever showing. If you just override setHighlighted: then you end up with a momentary selection effect.

so you'll have these two methods:

```
- (void)setHighlighted: (BOOL)highlighted animated: (BOOL)animated
{
    // don't highlight
}

- (void)setSelected: (BOOL)selected animated: (BOOL)animated 
{
    // don't select
    //[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer. More people need to upvote it.

Comment: @sam Agreed. This method only works if you have a UITableViewCell subclass (which the original question mentioned) and in my opinion is the better solution.

Comment: I have to uncomment [super setSelected:selected animated:animated] to get isSelected property working.

Answer (score 60):

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 1):

By far the easier method - in my opinion - to achieve this, is by setting the Table View attributes checkbox in the Interface Builder screen where it says "Show Selection on Touch". See the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Unchecking that option seems to have no effect. However, I just found a workaround which I've posted at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22936734/804616

Answer (score -1):

What has worked for me in the past is just putting:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated { }
```

In my UITableViewCell subclasses (because it won't call super and make itself highlighted).
Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: thx joe, but i've tried that and it does not prevent the blue gradient seletion background

Comment: i edited my Q above to include that i tried this and it did not have the desired effect

Answer (score -11):

How about this?

```
// disable user interaction
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```