# a problem when disable Show selection on touch of UITableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I use IB and uncheck the 'Show selection on touch' but it still show blue highlight on cell that is selected. Is this a bug with apple or I am getting something wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is probably a bug in IB as you see in Documentation that table view does not have any property for the shows Selection on touch. It is the property of tableview cell rather. So the checkbox should not be present in the IB. Probably you can file a bug with apple and see what they say about it.

For getting the effect you should do it like:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
                [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
            }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I too feel it's most likely a bug. However, I just chanced upon a perfect workaround based on the following observations.

- [The cell is `highlighted` on touch down and `selected` on touch up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835388/804616).
- Both `-setHighlighted:animated:` and `-setSelected:animated:` highlight the cell according to its selection style, i.e., turning either of them on while the other is off highlights the cell.
- The cell is born with `highlighted` turned off (typically, else the solution below just needs an appropriate tweak which is easy to figure out based on your specific situation).

Given the above, just subclass UITableViewCell and override `setHighlighted:animated:` without calling `super`'s implementation. Thus, all efforts to turn `highlighted` on would be suppressed and the highlighting would happen only on touch up and not on touch down which is exactly what is expected when turning off 'Show Selection on Touch'.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // hack to get the effect of unchecking "Show Selection on Touch" option of UITableView in IB which has no effect
}
```

On touch up, the cell is `selected` but it is not `animated`. If you want the animation, I found that calling a delegate method as shown below animates the selection.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_itemsTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    return indexPath;
}
```