# What is the difference between a highlighted UITableViewCell and a selected UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

A UITableViewCell reflects two distinct states: Highlighted and Selected.

For me, they sound identical so what exactly are the differences?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Highlight** happens on touch down.

**Selected** happens on touch up, followed by the call to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. In a standard `UITableView`, there is usually a small delay between the highlight and the select.

Answer (score 4):

From appearance point of view:

[Selected Cell:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/selected)

> The selection affects the appearance of labels, image, and background. When the selected state of a cell is set to YES, it draws the background for selected cells with its title in white.

The background will be drawn based on `selectionStyle` & `selectedBackgroundView` values. I could not really see any white titles as Apple documentation mentioned. I just see the background changes as expected.

[Highlighted Cell:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/highlighted)

> The highlighting affects the appearance of labels, image, and background. When the highlighted state of a cell is set to YES, labels are drawn in their highlighted text color (default is white).
> Note that for highlighting to work properly, you must fetch the cell’s labels using the textLabel and detailTextLabel properties and set each label’s highlightedTextColor property; for images, get the cell’s image using the imageView property and set the UIImageView object’s highlightedImage property.

Again I don't really that see that the default highlighted text color is white.

So I conclude that selected cell appearance affects the background of the cell while the highlighted cell affects the labels text colors as well as the image (if highlightedImage property is set)