# Highlighting UITableViewCell covers UIView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UIView that is just a colored square in my subclass of UITableViewCell. It is on the LHS of the UITableViewCell.

Depending on the data, I show the colored square.  The problem is when I highlight the cell, the UIView gets covered.  Is there something that changes this behavior?  Or do I need to highlight the cell with a color with less than the default iOS blue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change the UITableViewCell's 'selectedBackgroundView' property to a UIView with a transparent background color.

Comment: Do you mean in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: to do:       `cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`?  I tried that but I get the same thing.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/899925/451588) seems to deal with the correct way to set it. What you want to do is instead set the 'selectedBackgroundView' to either a new UIView with a clear background color(rather than modifying the current one), or a UIImageView(presumably with transparency).

The question and answer also deal with a bunch of other issues related to what you're trying to do, such as the effects resulting from setting the 'selectionStyle' to 'UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone'.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cell's backgroundView to nil.