# How to get rid of the table cell's selectionStyle but still recieve setSelected/setHighlighted calls

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've tried the method presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/899925/1064869), and everything works except that I cannot make the `selectedBackgroundView` transparent, it stays white. In my custom `UITableViewCell` class I have:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    UIView *bkgView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];
    bkgView.alpha = 0.5;
    bkgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = bkgView;
}
```

I've also called `[self setNeedsDisplay];` in the `setSelected` method.

What I want is to remove the blue highlight (from `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue`
, I don't want to set this to `UITableViewCellSelectionNone` as it will disable the `setHighlight/Selected` calls) and still have the highlight/select methods called. I'm so very nearly there, it's just that the `selectedBackgorundView` remains white! If I set it to `redColor` or `blueColor`, it will appear as red or blue, but when I put `clearColor`, it shows as white. I thought about setting the background with `colorWithPatternImage` using a transparent PNG image, but I'd like to avoid this.

I prefer to try and figure this out as it's a lot cleaner to rely on these two method calls, and I also want to retain the use of the disclosure indicator which becomes white when selected, which will otherwise stay dark if I use `UITableViewCellSelectionNone`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: and returning nil. 
That way you still get notified when a Cell is going to be selected. However, it won't actually get selected, and from there you can manage selection yourself without having to deal with the control's default styling.

Answer (score 0):

you use the selectedBackgroundView to override the blue

in viewForRow: method:

```
     UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the background view and the selectedBackgroundView:

```
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.backgroundView = view;

    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = view;
```

Then override `- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated`

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    self.backgroundView.hidden = highlighted;
}
```

Comment: Nope, the only solution thus far is to use a transparent PNG.