# Custom cell sublayers and UITableViewCell selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uikit, cagradientlayer

How can I make a custom sublayer in a `UITableViewCell` disappear in `setSelected:animated:`?

**Context:**

I've added a custom background layer to my `UITableViewCell` by adding a `CAGradientLayer` inside of `drawRect:`, like so:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    [[self providerLabel] setTextColor:kOUBlue];
    [self addGrayLayer];
}

- (void)addGrayLayer{
    [[[self contentView] layer] insertSublayer:[self grayGradientLayer] atIndex:0];
}

- (CAGradientLayer *) grayGradientLayer{
  if (!_grayGradientLayer) {
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    UIColor *white = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:2];
    UIColor *gray = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.96 green:0.96 blue:0.96 alpha:1];

    [gradient setColors:@[(id)white.CGColor, (id)gray.CGColor]];
    [gradient setFrame:[self bounds]];

    _grayGradientLayer = gradient;

  }

  return _grayGradientLayer;
}
```

When the user taps on a cell, the blue highlighting doesn't appear. So I've attempted to hide the `CAGradientLayer` in `setSelected:animated:` like so:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

  // Configure the view for the selected state

  if (selected) {
    [[self grayGradientLayer] setHidden:YES];
  }else{
    [[self grayGradientLayer] setHidden:NO];
  }

  [[self contentView] setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The blue background appears, but not until the push animation begins. Is there any way for me to make the default blue appear immediately? I've also tried to add a second colored `CAGradientLayer` and swap them manually, but it seems to me that the cell doesn't redraw immediately after I hide the layer in `setSelected:`.

I've tried to force the cell to redraw, using `setNeedsDisplay` with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to move ` [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];` under your logic. You're not hiding the grayLayer until after it's superview calls set selected.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around, I [found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899862/uitableviewcell-how-to-prevent-blue-selection-background-w-o-borking-isselected?rq=1), I realized I was using the wrong method. It turns out I had to use the `setHighlighted:animated:` method.

My new code looks like this:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated{

   [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];

   if (highlighted) {
     [[self grayGradientLayer] setHidden:YES];
   }else{
     [[self grayGradientLayer] setHidden:NO];
   }
}
```